# Why is this one, pointless line of code the only thing that makes this function work?

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ and decided to make a bunch of small, short functions to practice. This following bit of code will give me an incorrect answer:

```
float pairwiseSum(float data[], int arraySize, int naive_sum_size=8) {
  if (arraySize <= naive_sum_size) {
    return naiveSum(data, arraySize);
  } else {
    int m = arraySize / 2;
    return pairwiseSum(&data[0], m) + pairwiseSum(&data[m], arraySize-m);
  }
}
```

naiveSum in this case just iterates through an array accumulates the sum and appears to work fine. If I have an array of 64 1s, it will tell me the sum is 288.

However, this version of the code works perfectly every time:

```
float pairwiseSum(float data[], int arraySize, int naive_sum_size=8) {
  if (arraySize <= naive_sum_size) {
    cout << "";
    return naiveSum(data, arraySize);
  } else {
    int m = arraySize / 2;
    return pairwiseSum(&data[0], m) + pairwiseSum(&data[m], arraySize-m);
  }
}
```

I'm using Fedora 21 and compiling with g++ 4.9.2

Why does one function work, but the other one fail?

Edit: the complete program as it appears in my main.cpp file is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


float naiveSum(float data[], int arraySize) {
  float sum;
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    sum += data[i];
  return sum;
}


// Divide-and-conquer algorithm is a little faster than the
// Kahan Summation Algorithm, but also less accurate.
float pairwiseSum(float data[], int arraySize, int naive_sum_size=8) {
  if (arraySize <= naive_sum_size) {
    //cout << "";
    return naiveSum(data, arraySize);
  } else {
    int m = arraySize / 2;
    return pairwiseSum(&data[0], m) + pairwiseSum(&data[m], arraySize-m);
  }
}


int main() {
  const int SIZE = 64;
  const int rndRange = 100;

  // generate random array
  srand(time(NULL));
  float xs[SIZE];
  for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    // +1 prevents division by zero
    //xs[i] = rand() % rndRange / (float)(rand() % rndRange + 1);
    xs[i] = 1;

  // Print kahan sum of random array
  //cout << "Kahan Sum: " << kahanSum(xs, SIZE) << endl << endl;
  cout << endl << pairwiseSum(xs, SIZE) << endl;

  return 1;
}
```

Edit: yes, it was indeed a problem with sum not being intialized. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Immediate red flag for _undefined behaviour_. Launch your debugger and check your array indices.

Comment: Because you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You're asking why a function you haven't shown isn't working.

Comment: "my complete program" is not a [MCVE]. How have you been debugging so far without an [MCVE]? \*boggle\*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sum` is not initialized in `naiveSum`. The rest is just undefined behavior (caused by indeterminate value in `sum`) manifesting itself differently with or without that irrelevant `cout << ""` line.

There are many different ways `cout << ""` can cause that indeterminate initial value of `sum` to end up being zero and thus create an appearance of `naiveSum` working properly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation for how cout << "" was making a difference. It seemed so odd to me and was wondering if it was executing in an order I didn't understand.

Comment: @user3471004: You have to look as assembly code to figure that out for sure. For example, the optimizer might have associated your `sum` with some CPU (FPU) register. Without that `cout` line the register contained some old non-zero value (from previous calculations) and your `naiveSum` appeared to work incorrectly. With that `cout` line that register was used for some purpose by `cout` and got zeroed out in the end, which caused your `naiveSum` to appear to work correctly. And this is just one possible explanation.

Comment: Basically, in real life, wherever your `sum` is stored (register, memory, etc), it will begin its life with some "garbage" value stored in that area by its previous "user". By adding that `cout << ""` line you effectively change the previous user and thus change the garbage it leaves behind. It is just so happens that `cout << ""` leaves "better" garbage (a zero value) in that area, which `sum` will later occupy. This is a pure accident though.